# How do I Bind to a Collection and Display Information Based on Selection through a Dialog Box in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am fairly new to WPF, and I'm currently creating a desktop application for work. I have been doing a bit of research on databinding and came across this How-to article in the MSDN Library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970558.aspx

Right now the problem I'm faced with is implementing this to my application.  I want to modify this by having the information displayed in a dialog box instead of the same window the collection is in.  How can I implement this in C#/xaml?

Comment: Well I wouldn't be asking the question if I found an answer in Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add another window to the project. Then you need to instantiate that window from your mainwindow trough a button click for instance. Then you have to set that new window datacontext.

See this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/964c77c3-1144-4a36-9658-52885d1d8c9e), it shows how to create another window and pass the datacontext.
Hope it helps.